# Are there any resolutions for $\mathbb{Z}$ over group algebra without topological <<model>>?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Let $G$ be group. Each cell partition of the universal cover of $K(G, 1)$ delivers a (projective?) resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over group algebra $\mathbb{Z}G$.

Can one construct  a  pair of contractable cell complex  and it's surjective map onto $K(G, 1)$, homotopically equivalent to universal cover, corresponding to given resolution of  $\mathbb{Z}$  over $\mathbb{Z}G$?

Or possibly at least a contractable cell complex with action of $G$ on it?

Comment: I think the only difficulty should be getting the $2$-skeleton: the boundary of a $1$-cell has to be just a difference of two $0$-cells, and it's not clear that you can always choose how to attach the $2$-cells such that you will get a simply connected space.